# JsonMappingException: Root name does not match expected

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jersey-client

My question is as follows:
**jackson desearlization: Two keys at root. How do i unwrap one and ignore the other?**
I want this problem to be solved without using a wrapper class as solved in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857009/jackson-desearlization-two-keys-at-root-how-do-i-unwrap-one-and-ignore-the-oth).
I am developing a jersey client application. I've configured a jackson data bind 
integrated with jersey.

```
Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> mixins = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>();
    mixins.put(Set.class, CollectionMixIn.class);
    return new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES,false)
            .setMixIns(mixins);
```

a minxin interface:

```
@JsonRootName("items")
interface CollectionMixIn {
}
```

the server returns a json response like this:

```
{"totalCount":6,"items":[{"id":62,"lat":30.2173,"lon":50.186405,"alt":0.0,"imageFileName":"DSC_0410 - Copy (3).JPG","imageFileSize":7671969,"imageFileSizeAsString":"7.32 MB"},{"id":65,"lat":30.2173,"lon":50.186405,"alt":0.0,"imageFileName":"DSC_0410 - Copy.JPG","imageFileSize":7671969,"imageFileSizeAsString":"7.32 MB"}]}
```

I read the above json by the help of jersey client:

```
 WebTarget target = webTarget.path("getPics");
 target = target.queryParam("nodeId", 67);
 Invocation.Builder builder =  target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
 Set<PicsDetail> res = builder.get(Set.class);
```

Note that `PicsDetail` is a POJO of mine. I want to read a collection of `PicsDetail`s. but I face this exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Error reading entity from input stream.
   at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:866)
   at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:783)
 ....
 ....
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Root name 'totalCount' does not match expected ('items') for type [collection type; class java.util.Set, contains [simple type, class java.lang.Object]]
   at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream@4f67eb2a; line: 1, column: 2]
   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)
```

the problem is that,

```
Root name 'totalCount' does not match expected ('items')
```

the response json contains `items` property, but jackson has not sense of it.Please help!
similar questions are resolved by a wrapper class.
I don't want to use a wrapper class like this:

```
class Wrapper{
   int totalCount;
   Set items;
}
```

similar questions:

- [jackson desearlization: two keys at root. how do i unwrap one and ignore the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857009/jackson-desearlization-two-keys-at-root-how-do-i-unwrap-one-and-ignore-the-oth)
- [Jackson: JSON parsing for array of parent elements : Root name '' does not match expected ('List')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883367/jackson-json-parsing-for-array-of-parent-elements-root-name-does-not-match)
- [JsonMappingException: Current token not START_OBJECT (needed to unwrap root name 'Transaction[]'), but START_ARRAY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075218/jsonmappingexception-current-token-not-start-object-needed-to-unwrap-root-name)